# Select closest value from table using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing some values with column `max_value`

```
max_value     
    100            
    250            
    320           
    160
```

So I want to select value which is closest to `max_value` by checking few condition listed below:

1) if i have value 111 then it should get only max_value = 160

2) if I have value=450 then it should get max_value = 320

3) if i have value=350 then it should get 320 because there is no value greater then 350 so it should fetch its nearest lower value

Mysql query :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
where max_value <='450' or max_value >='450' 
ORDER BY max_value ASC LIMIT 1.
```

Comment: Why not 100 for 111?

Comment: @ I want  only one record,  111 is greater then 99 but less then 160

Comment: 100 is the closest value to 111. Clarify what you want.

Comment: yes i want only one record  that too value should check greater than and less than that can be done by order by clause

Comment: Edit your question and explain. Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: ok i will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery which returns the min `max_value` that is *greater than or equal* to the value you search for, or if it does not exist the max `max_value` that is *smaller* to that value:

```
select * from tablename
where max_value = coalesce(
  (select min(max_value) from tablename where max_value >= 350),  
  (select max(max_value) from tablename where max_value < 350)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uBS4wRfVWEHCvMitMxoQzg/2).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create an absolute difference between the input value and the max value, and then sort on that value to fetch the row with lowest absolute difference. But this would get the closest value whether above or below the input number. However, your revised requirements suggest that if there is a value **just above** the input value, then you would prefer that instead.

```
SELECT max_value 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY 
  -- give first priority to values above 450
  CASE WHEN max_value >= 450 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC
  ABS(450 - max_value) ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

But then, unfortunately above approach cannot use Indexing, and will be slow on a large table. So, to utilize index on `max_value` column, we can use `UNION` on two different SELECT queries getting to closest value just above 450, and just below 450.  So try the following instead:

```
SELECT dt.max_value FROM 
(
  (
    -- getting the closest value just above 450
    SELECT max_value, 1 AS priority
    FROM your_table 
    WHERE max_value >= 450   -- notice >=
    ORDER BY max_value ASC   -- ASC LIMIT 1 to get value just above
    LIMIT 1
  )

  UNION 

  (
    -- getting the closest value just below 450
    SELECT max_value, 2 
    FROM your_table 
    WHERE max_value <= 450    -- notice <=
    ORDER BY max_value DESC   -- DESC LIMIT 1 to get value just below
    LIMIT 1
  ) 
) dt 

-- first priority to get the closest value above, then only below
ORDER BY dt.priority ASC
```

Comment: i got one issue if i select 111 output should be 160 not 100

Comment: @Anonymous that is what forpas is mentioning in the comments above. Please edit the question and make your requirements clear. What if the input value is **350** ?

Comment: i  request you can you suggest me short query instead of above used union quey it is too large for  single output

Comment: @Anonymous query with more words does not mean bad if it will be extremely efficient and use indexes properly on a large table. your priority should be to write efficient queries instead of worrying about the length of the query string.

Comment: actually I am unable to understand  so  i thought that is their any simple way  to write

Comment: can you please  suggest me simplest way to write this query

Comment: @Anonymous . . . The first query using `order by` is the simplest way to write the query.